# Как правильно сделать GET-запрос из form?

Tags: javascript

По заданию мне нужно получить данные из формы с помощью GET-запроса. Вот часть моя кода, которая не работает.

```
    const submit = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('coordinates-form'));
        response = fetch("php/get_data.php", {
            method: 'GET',
            body: formData,
        }).then(response => response.text())
            .then(response => document.getElementById('result-table').innerHTML = response);

    };
    butt.addEventListener('click', submit);
```

При этом если поменять параметр method: 'GET' на method: 'POST' всё работает прекрасно. Как правильно сделать запрос? Мне нужно, чтобы содержимое get_data.php появлялось на странице html. Гуглил как мог, ничего не нашел.

Comment: Полагаю что проблема в "body: formData". Для GET запроса лучше передавайте параметры в УРЛ

Comment: Действительно, убрал эту строку и всё заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: Тогда выберите ответ правильным, что бы вопрос закрыть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю что проблема в "body: formData".